# Ticket refund due to medical condition in transit

Tags: transit, refunds, emergencies

My parents were flying to Houston from Karachi and had a 3 day stay at Istanbul on the way from Karachi from Turkish Airline. I booked a return ticket for them.

My mother's tibia bone got fractured in Istanbul due to an accident and had to be hospitalized. Of course she could not travel, so I changed their flight to Houston from Istanbul to next week ($250 fee) so that she could get a surgery in Istanbul and I could think about what to do with the flight ticket.

After her surgery, she wishes to come back home to Karachi.
I am thinking about booking a new ticket from Istanbul to Karachi for them and apply for refunding the other ticket.

What are the chances of getting a full refund by providing the medical report?

Comment: Entirely depends on the airline. Call them and ask.

Comment: @RupertMorrish Usually best to have an idea of what the correct change fee should be before you call as there are not many airline agents who can calculate changes correctly. Once I was incorrectly quoted nearly 5000 USD for what eventually turned out to be a 75 USD refund.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I changed their flight to Houston from Istanbul to next week ($250 fee) so that she could get a surgery in Istanbul and I could think about what to do with the flight ticket.

Your first step should be to contact your parents' travel insurer, who can probably re-arrange your trip for when they are both back on your feet, and directly arrange refunds and compensation for them.

If they are not helpful, then in terms of refunding a partially flown ticket, the cheapest TK fares on Karachi-Houston include the following provision:

```
 CANCELLATIONS

   TICKET IS NON-REFUNDABLE IN CASE OF NO-SHOW.
     NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
      IN THE EVENT OF NO SHOW - WHEN REFUND IS
      REQUESTED AFTER DEPARTURE OF THE ORIGINALLY
      SCHEDULED FLIGHT-
      NOT PERMITTED EVEN FOR MEDICAL REASON
      FOR NON REFUNDABLE TICKETS THE -YR- SURCHARGE
      WILL NOT BE REFUNDED.
```

What this means in particular is that you must cancel your ticket and apply for a refund *before* your scheduled flight is due to depart. (That means your newly changed flight from Istanbul to Houston.) If you simply "no show" (fail to turn up without telling the airline), then your ticket will become valueless.

Continuing to read the penalties category,

```
 AFTER DEPARTURE
     CANCELLATIONS PERMITTED FOR CANCEL/REFUND.
     NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
      FOR CANCELLATIONS AFTER DEPARTURE THE REFUND GIVEN
      WILL BE THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE FARE PAID AND
      THE APPLICAPLE FARE FOR THE JOURNEY FLOWN.
      APPLICABLE FARE FOR THE JOURNEY FLOWN IS THE ONE
      THAT SET AT THE SAME RBD WITH THE ORIGINAL FARE
      PAID.
      IF NO FARE EXISTS FOR THE FLOWN JOURNEY
      ON THE SAME RBD WITH THE ORGINALFARE
      ANY FARE SET ON A HIGHER RBD  WILL BE ACCEPTED.
      -----------------------------------
```

Provided you cancel in advance, you need to find the lowest possible one-way fare from Karachi to Istanbul in the same booking class (RBD) as your parents originally flew, calculated on the day they originally purchased the ticket. That is the cost of your one way flight; any remainder would be your refund. A service fee may also apply from your travel agent.

Comment: This is the base of the answer.
If you have fares that can be changed -> free to do.
If not -> travel / other insurance to the rescue.

Short answer: the airline is not liable for your personal accidents.

Comment: Please do not use codeblock for anything that isn't code, especially when quoteblock is obviously available, suitable, and acknowledged.

Comment: @Nij I've quoted pre-formatted (fixed-width) text taken from a GDS. In particular the level of indentation is meaningful to both the human and the computer parsers of this text. Quote block uses variable-width characters and would require me to spend a long time reproducing the original formatting. Personally, I don't think it is suitable. If I misunderstand what you're saying—let me know.

Comment: Quoteblock can be indented by levels, and the point is that the computer and human parsers on Stack Exchange have trouble with it. In particular, the sentences don't need to be cut at arbitrary points to preserve meaning.

Comment: @Nij I think I would prefer to stick with the industry-specified way of presenting the data (including the line limit) rather than try to make the information look nice and possibly mangle it along the way. (ATPCO fare rules are “code” to be interpreted by a machine in the same way that C++ is code.) I have provided a human-readable analysis outside the quoted data displays.